# How to block-average in a for-loop with non-uniform data lenght

Tags: matlab, for-loop, moving-average

I'm a newby in Matlab, and I need to estimate the average value of an non-uniform data length in a vector. I have a matrix with a flag column (ones and zeroes), time stamp, and my variable of interest. Basically, the data (from an intrument) is measuring in flag:zero (a reference value) for N amount of time, and flag:one in the sample for N amount of time. N is variable but oscilates between 28-30 secs.

What I need to implement is to estimate the mean value of each flag:zero and flag:one for each of the measured cycles.

What I have done so far:

```
for i=1:numel(inlet)

if inlet(i)== 1; co2_0(i)=NaN; end

end

for i=1:numel(inlet)

if inlet(i)== 0; co2_1(i)=NaN; end

end
```

What this does is basically putting NaN when the condition (i.e., zero or one) is not met.

Then, I tried to do a nested for/if loop, but this is the part where I cannot estimate the mean values

```
for i = 1:1:length(inlet)

if inlet (i) == 1
    co2_avg(i) = co2_1 (i);
end


for j=1:length(co2_avg)
    co2_mu (j) = mean(co2_avg);
end

end
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's unclear over which values you want the mean. If you just want the means of column 3 when column 1 is either 0 or 1, you can just do `m0 = mean( X( X(:,1) == 0, 3 ) )` and `m1 = mean( X( X(:,1) == 1, 3 ) )`...

Comment: Hi Wolfie,yes, it is column 3 and the idea of the code you shared is kind of what I need. But that gives the mean value of all data when zero or one, according to the condition. What I do not have is the for loop to move each 29 data points (number of data points between 1 and 0).

Comment: "kind of what I need *but*..."? Does that resolve your issue or is something still outstanding?

Comment: There is still the part of the block average. Let's say the matrix is 3 columns and 116 rows. That's 2 cycles in "one" and 2 cycles in "zero". Then, the final result should be 4 values of the average of the 2 cycles in zero and the two cylcles in one

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's pretty difficult to try and interpret your descriptions, it would be *much* clearer if you just gave a small example and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like Wolfie said, you can simply use `X(X(:,1)==1, 3)` instead of `X(:,3)` in any place you want to average only on those that have 1 in the first column, and similarly for 0.
2. If you want to calculate the average while ignoring NaN values, you should use [nanmean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) instead of mean.

(generally speaking, there is a "NaN-ignoring" equivalent function for most simple functions in Matlab: nanmin, nanmax, nanstd, etc.)

Comment: Caveat: All those functions require Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.